# Whenever I move an object the entire scene is re-rendered

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering

Whenever I move one of the objects in my scene, blender automatically re-renders the entire scene as if I had pressed the render button. How can I turn this off?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out after 11 minutes of painstaking button pushing.

Uncheck the box that says "auto render"